# Android Studio: Putting canvas and button using layout

Tags: android, canvas

I am reading a book on building an app called "Dot Smasher."

I decide to approach one of the task by adding a button above canvas.
I decide to use LinearLayout and did the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Timer timer;
private DotSmasherCanvas canvas;
private DotSmasherTimerTask task;
private Button button;
private LinearLayout layout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("DotSmasher");
    canvas = new DotSmasherCanvas(getBaseContext());
    timer = new Timer();
    task = new DotSmasherTimerTask(canvas);
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 1500);

    button = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button);

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.addView(canvas);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



}
}
```

This is the xml file -- activity_main.xml:

[image]

I am able to get it work if I only did **setContentView(canvas);**

But not above, what did I do wrong?

There's no error display in Android Studio until I try to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to understand how layouts work.  You're calling findViewById before calling setContentView.  That won't work-  until you set a content view, there's no place to search for a view.  And you shouldn't mix xml layouts and programmatic views unless you have a very dynamic layout-  either your DotSmasherCanvas should be in the layout, or none of it should be in xml (probably the first).